# Как сохранить состояние у listView?

Tags: java, android, listview

Есть 3 таба для навигации, в каждом табе фрагмент, во фрагменте listview.

При навигации по табам, пропадает весь листвью со всеми данными. Если же перезагружать адаптер

`listView.setAdapter(adapter);`

То состояние листвью не теряется после навигации.

> MainActivity

```
 private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new MyAudioFragment(), "1 tab");
        adapter.addFragment(new TopAudioFragment(), "2 tab");
        adapter.addFragment(new SearchAudioFragment(), "3 tab");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
```

> MyAudioFragment

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
        listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        player =  ((Application)getActivity().getApplication()).getPlayer();
        state = listView.onSaveInstanceState();
        listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {


            }

            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                 int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                if(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount!=0)
                {

                    if(flag_loading == false)
                    {
                        flag_loading = true;
                        LocalOffset += 30;
                        try {
                            loadAudioList(LocalOffset);
                        }catch (IOException e){

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        try {

           /* if(adapter != null)
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);*/

            loadAudioList(LocalOffset);

        }catch (IOException e){

        }


        return view;
    }


private void loadAudioList(int offset) throws IOException{
        wrapper.MyAudio(offset, UserStorage.getUid(), new WrapperVK.WrapperVKActionsAudio() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ArrayList data) {
                final ArrayList dataToUiThread = data;
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                      if(adapter == null) {
                            adapter = new AudioAdapter(getActivity(), dataToUiThread);
                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }else {
                            adapter.addAll(dataToUiThread);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            flag_loading = false;
                        }

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onFail(String data) {
                System.out.println(data);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

> activity_main.xml

```
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabTextColor="#fff"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabGravity="fill"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Как правильно сохранить состояние каждого listView?

Comment: Покажите как вы меняете фрагменты

Comment: @IvanVovk Добавил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смысл в том, что в ListView, пока вы не указали **adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()**  данные не меняется, как данные вы загрузили при инициализации адаптера, так они там и остались, как вы выполнили команду по обновлению данных в адаптере, только тогда происходит обновление listView.

Если у вас много фрагментов, то для сохранения структуры ViewPager установите значение ViewPager.**setOffscreenPageLimit**(количествофрагментов), так как по умолчанию ViewPager хранит текущий фрагмент и два соседних: справа и слева.

Comment: То что нужно ! Спасибо !